# Heston we have a problem, my computer wont start "usb 1-1.2.1:device descriptor read/64, error -32" does anybody know what this means?

Tags: boot, usb

My computer wont start (Ubuntu 16.04) and it displays this error message

"`usb 1-1.2.1:device descriptor read/64, error -32`"

I have been booting off this USB (Sandisk ultra fit 128GB) for a while now and it has been working fine until now.

The other error messages aren't the same and their solutions don't work.If anyone has some idea on what the problem is or how to fix it that would be great.

Comment: I think the city is ***Houston***. But I'm not a rocket scientist.

Comment: `32` is a gerneric broken pipe error I think (`#define EPIPE           32      /* Broken pipe */`)